# Weird copying error after updating to MacOs 13.0.1 (22A400)

Tags: macos, copy-paste, rsync

I have been trying to copy some folders between 2 external hard drives and I am getting this weird error.

None of the folders is locked; this never happened before updating to 13.0.1.

Any idea how to solve this?

[image]

EDIT:

Both dicks are normal USB External Physical Volume • Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and I use a USB-C cable to mount them. I cannot remember if I have used rsync in the past for the problematic folders. Rsync seems to be working now but simply copy-paste produces the error.

Comment: How are the external disks attached to your Mac? USB using HFS+ or APFS, or are they networked disks on a NAS? See my answer below for the relevance, and depending on what you info you can add to your question I may be able to update my answer.

Comment: Which specific folders do cause issues? What is the filesystem format used on the source and the target disk?

Comment: @nohillside the one is ExFat the other is Mac OS Extended (Journaled). It also happens with other folders. I have rwx rights to both discs.

Comment: Please a) answer all the questions raised in the comments and b) edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to copy files in Finder that you have previously copied using `rsync` (from your included tags, and the screenshot). I spent quite some time a few weeks ago with exactly the same problem, where I was trying to delete files on a Samba share that I had previously copied from Mac to my NAS using `rsync`. I'd originally used `rsync` for its ability to resume after failure and be a bit more transparent in progress while moving 300GB+ of data, rather than rely on the opaqueness of Finder's progress bar.

A good possibility is that the issue is due to invalid characters in the filenames that were caused by a missing UTF-8 conversion in the `rsync` copy. I found this with a lot of accented characters in the filenames of a lot of music files (too many Krautrock umlauts...). When viewed in Midnight Commander via the share, the first character was invariably invalid and represented as `?`. Finder did not show the filename as invalid, but refused to touch it otherwise with the same error you are experiencing.

Apparently there are different 'Normalisation' forms of UTF-8 encoding, and macOS uses an Apple specific one which needs to be accounted for in any `rsync` copy to a non-macOS machine.

There is a good explanation of the problem in this Question.

[Rsync with Linux server: special character problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148799/rsync-with-linux-server-special-character-problem?rq=1)

And the (very) technical explanation for different Unicode Normalisation Forms here. It's to do with methods for string comparisons, amongst other things.

http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Apparently the conversion should always be `--iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8` regardless of direction. This is because the order is `--iconv=LOCAL,REMOTE`,  not from, to . As the local is always macOS this works as expected.

Now, you did not specify whether the external disks were attached directly to your Mac, or whether they were hosted on another machine. If they are on another networked machine you will probably have to work with them directly on that machine. If the disks are local (HFS+ or APFS) you might be able to 'fix' the affected files by attempting an `rsync` local-to-local copy using  the `--iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8` conversion. I have not encountered this with locally attached disks so cannot provide any sort of guarantee.

`rsync -aivP --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8 local_source local_destination`

Also, ensure you are using a current version of `rsync`. The one supplied with Ventura is too old, so use one installed from Homebrew or similar. The `utf-8-mac` conversion is also specific to the Mac versions of `rsync` and `iconv` and won't be found in a Linux version.

Comment: Hi. Both dicks are normal USB External Physical Volume • Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and I use a USB-C cable to mount them. I cannot remember if I have used `rsync` in the past for the problematic folders. `Rsync` seems to be working now but simply copy-paste produces the error.

Comment: Thx. Please add that information by editing your question, where it belongs.

Comment: Hi. How could I solve the problem. Ideally, I want to be able to just copy-past folders between locally-mounted EHD without getting this error.