# Error permission while copying files after recent update to Ventura

Tags: macbook-pro, permission

I have been getting this error message from some folders that are in an external hard drive while trying to copy them in another external drive.

Both drives are connected with usb-c usb-c cables.

Before the update to Ventura, I never had this problem.

[image]

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I’m voting to put this question on hold because it currently just states a fact and doesn't actually ask a question.

Comment: This is the same question you raised as I previously gave an answer to in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/451548/221742 Basically it boils down to you having files with non-Apple UTF-8 characters in the filenames. Although my answer related to my experience with files on an SMB share the principle is the same. You'll need to identify those files and rename them. I provided a suggestion for a solution in that answer (local to local rsync with iconv), though I have not tested it, so there's no guarantee.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths your previously suggested solution did not help. I am still getting this error when trying to copy a folder across 2 external drives and I cannot.

Comment: Then please edit the original question to add details, otherwise people will propose the same answer again. While doing so, please also address the clarifications asked for in the comments.

Comment: The error is self explanatory.  Did you do a [Get Info](https://osxdaily.com/2021/04/27/using-get-info-keyboard-shortcut-mac/) (`Cmd-I`) on the file(s) in question?  What are the owners and permissions?